# DoublyLinked List

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, nodes, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to implement a **Doubly Linked List**. I implemented it with two sentinel nodes (head and tail) , implemented add method to add always as first element in the list and get method to bring element at specific index. The problem is when I try to execute the method `get(index)` it keeps getting me wrong answers. Can anyone figure what's wrong with my implementation?

Thanks in advance.

This is my Code:

```
public class MyLinkedList<E> extends AbstractList<E> {

    LLNode<E> head;
    LLNode<E> tail;
    int size;

    /** Create a new empty LinkedList */
    public MyLinkedList() {
        // TODO: Implement this method
        head = new LLNode<E>(null);
        tail = new LLNode<E>(null);
        head.next = tail ; 
        tail.prev=head ; 
        size = 0; 
    }

    /**
     * Appends an element to the end of the list
     * @param element The element to add
     */
    public boolean add(E element ) 
    {
        // TODO: Implement this method
        if(element==null) throw new NullPointerException ("NullpointerException")  ;    

        LLNode<E> current = new LLNode<E>(element); 
        current.next = head.next ; 
        current.prev = current.next.prev ; 
        head.next = current  ; 
        current.next.prev = current ; 
        size++ ; 
        return true;
    }

    /** Get the element at position index 
     * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException if the index is out of bounds. */
    public E get(int index) 
    {
        // TODO: Implement this method.
        if(index>size-1 || index<0) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("IndexOutOfBoundsException") ; 
        LLNode<E> theOne = getNode(index) ; 
        return theOne.data;
    }
    private LLNode<E> getNode(int index){
        LLNode<E> current = head ; 
        for(int i = 0 ; i<=index ; i++) {
            current = current.next ; 
        }
        return current;

    }
class LLNode<E> 
{

    LLNode<E> prev;
    LLNode<E> next;
    E data;

    // TODO: Add any other methods you think are useful here
    // E.g. you might want to add another constructor

    public LLNode(E e) 
    {
        this.data = e;
        this.prev = null;
        this.next = null;
    }
```

Comment: What is it coming as ? Is it always the data of the next node , what you are expecting ?

Comment: list.get(0) brings item at first index and list.get(1) gives me null if it is 2 item list .

Comment: Try this : private LLNode<E> getNode(int index){
    LLNode<E> current = head ; 
    for(int i = 0 ; i<index ; i++) {
        current = current.next ; 
    }
    return current;

}

Comment: null >> so it points to head

Comment: I think the problem is in pointers but can`t get it

Comment: I dont think so it should give null now . Why it was giving null earlier was , you were running loop till the index . when you do getNode(1) , it was going inside the loop and incrementing the current to current.next which is null . Hence I removed the = from the condition

Comment: Suppose i have a list with two elements ("a" and"b") after i removed "=" list.get(0) gets me null . With(=) it gets me "b"  .

Comment: Please check the list before getNode() method call . If you remove = , it should return current. and current is pointing to head and current .data = a